# Netbeans 7.3 JSP parser bug

Tags: netbeans

I just upgraded my netbeans to 7.3 and I found a strange bug. In the project tree there is a JSP parsing error but no error message in the editor window.
Is anybody knows how can I get the JSP parser output. (e.g. logging)

Answer (score 0):

I found the parser's output in the cache directory: cache/.../my_file.jsp.err